# Select Multiple Occurrences using 1 expression

Tags: select, xpath

I'm an absolute noob with this so please forgive me for not using the correct terminology but I will attempt to be as precise and detailed as possible.

I use the following expression to obtain occurrence "HPI-White". Is there a way to select the other color occurrence from --- SAMPLE CODE --- without having to create separate expressions? I can change the # value after /Occurence[1] to get what I want but that seems redundant.

```
/XMLReport/Report/PreflightResult/PreflightResultEntry[3]/PreflightResultEntryMessage/StringContext/Occurences/Occurence[1]/VarPairs/VarPair[1]/VarValue/text()
```

--- SAMPLE CODE ---

```
 <PreflightResultEntryMessage xml:lang="en-US">
      <Message>Spot color Dieline, HPI-White, PANTONE 105 C, PANTONE 127 C, PANTONE 7636 C, PANTONE Black C, PANTONE Blue 0821 C, PANTONE Magenta 0521 C, PANTONE Rhodamine Red C, PANTONE Warm Red C, PANTONE Yellow C is used (11x on page 1)</Message>
      <StringContext>
        <BaseString>Spot color %[]SpotColorName% is used</BaseString>
        <ConstantPairs>
          <ConstantPair>
            <ConstantName>Category</ConstantName>
            <ConstantValue>Check</ConstantValue>
          </ConstantPair>
          <ConstantPair>
            <ConstantName>ActionID</ConstantName>
            <ConstantValue>2078</ConstantValue>
          </ConstantPair>
        </ConstantPairs>
        <Occurences>
          <Occurence>
            <VarPairs>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>SpotColorName</VarName>
                <VarValue>HPI-White</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>Instances</VarName>
                <VarValue>0</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
            </VarPairs>
            <Location maxX="289.431" maxY="421.867" minX="89.431" minY="400.603" page="0"/>
          </Occurence>
          <Occurence>
            <VarPairs>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>SpotColorName</VarName>
                <VarValue>PANTONE Yellow C</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>Instances</VarName>
                <VarValue>0</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
            </VarPairs>
            <Location maxX="68.076" maxY="386.523" minX="50.717" minY="365.259" page="0"/>
          </Occurence>
          <Occurence>
            <VarPairs>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>SpotColorName</VarName>
                <VarValue>PANTONE Warm Red C</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>Instances</VarName>
                <VarValue>0</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
            </VarPairs>
            <Location maxX="99.352" maxY="386.523" minX="81.993" minY="365.259" page="0"/>
          </Occurence>
          <Occurence>
            <VarPairs>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>SpotColorName</VarName>
                <VarValue>PANTONE Rhodamine Red C</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>Instances</VarName>
                <VarValue>0</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
            </VarPairs>
            <Location maxX="130.628" maxY="386.523" minX="113.269" minY="365.259" page="0"/>
          </Occurence>
          <Occurence>
            <VarPairs>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>SpotColorName</VarName>
                <VarValue>PANTONE Magenta 0521 C</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>Instances</VarName>
                <VarValue>0</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
            </VarPairs>
            <Location maxX="161.904" maxY="386.523" minX="144.545" minY="365.259" page="0"/>
          </Occurence>
          <Occurence>
            <VarPairs>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>SpotColorName</VarName>
                <VarValue>PANTONE Blue 0821 C</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>Instances</VarName>
                <VarValue>0</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
            </VarPairs>
            <Location maxX="193.18" maxY="386.523" minX="175.821" minY="365.259" page="0"/>
          </Occurence>
          <Occurence>
            <VarPairs>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>SpotColorName</VarName>
                <VarValue>PANTONE Black C</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>Instances</VarName>
                <VarValue>0</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
            </VarPairs>
            <Location maxX="224.455" maxY="386.523" minX="207.096" minY="365.259" page="0"/>
          </Occurence>
          <Occurence>
            <VarPairs>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>SpotColorName</VarName>
                <VarValue>PANTONE 105 C</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>Instances</VarName>
                <VarValue>0</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
            </VarPairs>
            <Location maxX="255.731" maxY="386.523" minX="238.372" minY="365.259" page="0"/>
          </Occurence>
          <Occurence>
            <VarPairs>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>SpotColorName</VarName>
                <VarValue>PANTONE 127 C</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>Instances</VarName>
                <VarValue>0</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
            </VarPairs>
            <Location maxX="287.007" maxY="386.523" minX="269.648" minY="365.259" page="0"/>
          </Occurence>
          <Occurence>
            <VarPairs>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>SpotColorName</VarName>
                <VarValue>PANTONE 7636 C</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>Instances</VarName>
                <VarValue>0</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
            </VarPairs>
            <Location maxX="318.283" maxY="386.523" minX="300.924" minY="365.259" page="0"/>
          </Occurence>
          <Occurence>
            <VarPairs>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>SpotColorName</VarName>
                <VarValue>Dieline</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
              <VarPair>
                <VarName>Instances</VarName>
                <VarValue>0</VarValue>
              </VarPair>
            </VarPairs>
            <Location maxX="364.928" maxY="472.927" minX="4.0725" minY="4.0722" page="0"/>
          </Occurence>
        </Occurences>
      </StringContext>
    </PreflightResultEntryMessage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the short answer is to replace `Occurence[1]` with `Occurence`.  Then you would get the following text returned:

```
HPI-WhitePANTONE Yellow CPANTONE Warm Red CPANTONE Rhodamine Red CPANTONE Magenta 0521 CPANTONE Blue 0821 CPANTONE Black CPANTONE 105 CPANTONE 127 CPANTONE 7636 CDieline
```

Probably not what you want.

So let's talk about XPath.  Its purpose is to select a set of nodes from an XML document.  The selected nodes may be text nodes, but in general, the idea is for it to return a node set and give it back to you for processing.  So a lot is going to depend on what tool you are using XPath with, and what you can do with a node-set when it hands you one.  What are you using XPath in conjunction with?  XSLT?  Python?  PHP?

Comment: Thank you bjimba! That is exactly what I wanted.

I'm building an automation workflow using ESKO software and XPath is one of the type of tools I can use. I'm just starting to delve into the world of XPath and I'm finding it a very powerful tool. Hopefully that makes sense ;-)

Thank you again!